# How to interpret the contents of ~/.gconf?

Tags: gconf, shortcut-keys, xml

Consider a key like

> /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/cycle_windows

I can access this this key using gconf-editor. However when I `cd` to `~/.gconf/apps/metacity` I find an empty file named `%gconf.xml` and a directory called `general` which contains another `%conf.xml` file which is like this:

```
<gconf>
    <entry name="num_workspaces" mtime="an integer here" type="int" value="4"/>
</gconf>
```

My questions are,

- If the keys are stored somewhere else other than `.gconf` what is the purpose of this directory and how can I interpret the contents of it?
- The other question is, where are these keys stored and how can I access them?

*P.S. I'm running 12.04 on virtual machine.*

Answer (score 0):

`~/.gconf` subfolders contain only the settings that were modified by the user. Original gconf settings can be found in `/usr/share/gconf/`. For example, the key `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/` you mentioned in your question is created using `/usr/share/gconf/schemas/metacity.schemas`. And when the user changes some settings in this key, they go to `~/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/%gconf.xml`.

BTW, gconf is superseded by dconf. Though some settings weren't transferred yet.